# Node.js forever error on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

Hey so I'm trying to run a node server on my raspbian machine and everytime I run forever it throws this error:

[image: Screendump from device]

If it's not possible to use forever on a raspberry pi, how would I manually write a daemon script

Answer (score 1):

Type:

```
sudo npm install -g daemon
```

to install the `daemon` dependency (globally)

Comment: What is that supposed to achieve?

Comment: The error message which you have posted states that the nodejs package `daemon` isn't installed. the command above will install it